# can rearranging a function cause the graph of that function to change?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

this is a very beginner graph question.
If I have the function:
$\frac{x}{\left(y-2\right)}\le1$

the graph (via Desmos) looks like this:

[image]

If I rearrange the function by multiplying both sides by $y-2$ I get this function:
$x\le y-2$

The graph of it looks like this:

[image]

I don't understand why the graphs might look different, since I'm just rearranging the functions. Please help me understand what I'm doing incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: Multiplying an inequality by  a negative (here when $y<2$) switches the direction of the inequality.